# How to resolve variable conflicts in header files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am writing an adaptive step size update algorithm in OpenSees (an opensource earthquake engineering simulation project written majorly in visual studio c++). I am facing a conflict between two variables having the same name in two different header files (namely, *windef.h* and *steelz01.h*). I need a way to resolve this conflict.

I am using *gnuplot-iostream.h* in my project, I am facing this conflict only when I include this header file, otherwise there is no conlfict, code is builidng perfectly.

Basically *gnuplot-iostream.h* is calling *windows.h*, which is further calling *windef.h*. I have added include gauards in steelz01.h file, but it did not resolve the issue.

When I change the varaibale name in steelz01.h to a different name, then also the code is perfectly building. No ISSUE found. But, I don't want to channge the name of the variable in steelz01, it has serious repercussions.

I am including header files like this

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
#include <SteelZ01.h>
```

This is how the variable SIZE is defined in steelz01

```
#define LOOP_NUM_LIMIT               30
const int SIZE = LOOP_NUM_LIMIT; //limit of array number
```

and in windef.h, it is defined like this

```
typedef struct tagSIZE
{
    LONG        cx;
    LONG        cy;
} SIZE, *PSIZE, *LPSIZE;

typedef SIZE               SIZEL;
typedef SIZE               *PSIZEL, *LPSIZEL;
```

Visual Studio 2017 is throwing this error,

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\shared\windef.h(190): error C2378: 'SIZE': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef

1>e:\phd working folder\0_ops_github\src\material\nd\reinforcedconcreteplanestress\steelz01.h(17): note: see declaration of 'SIZE'
```

I am expecting a way to resolve this conflict and a successful build.

Comment: Why do you need the variable `SIZE` to begin with? Why can't you use the macro? And better yet, replace the macro with a proper constant variable.

Comment: Exporting a variable named just `SIZE` is a serious trouble. It's a bad design, that other programmers have to struggle later with. C++ solution - use `namespace SteelZ01 {`. And don't use `#define`, use `static constexpr`.

Comment: As I told, it is an open source project (a static library), the authors of *steelz01* defined it in that way. I can change the definition of `SIZE`, but the problem is I have to change the variable name in all the inheritances of *steelz01*

Comment: We can't help with mistakes other people make when you can't correct them.

Comment: Then you should report it as a bug to the authors of the project.

Comment: @PasserBy, Thank you very much. I don't know what is the mistake in the code (is using `#define` a mistake?). Could you please tell

Comment: `#define` isn't so much a mistake as something you should avoid. `#define` causes a simple text replacement that takes place before the compiler starts compiling. Wherever `LOOP_NUM_LIMIT` exists in the code, it is mindlessly replaced with 38. This one I deem reasonably safe, but it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to put include statement in namespace,

```
namespace ABC
{
    #include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
}

namespace PQR
{
   #include <SteelZ01.h>
}
```

Call:

```
ABC::SIZE
PQR::SIZE
```

This will not change any code of existing libraries. However, author of library using common names hence suggest him to keep common name under namespace to reduce any conflict.

Comment: This is interesting. I will implement the header files in a namespace and let you know about this. Thank you very much

Comment: This does assume the headers provide the complete definitions of everything (e.g. there aren't functions in a separate source file that - for example - might be provided as a separate object file or library and the program would not link with this approach).

Comment: No header file contains only declarations. I have a separate .cpp file which consists of all member function definitions. Does this namespace approach has any problems??

Comment: This will treat definition and declaration separate. I don't think so this will create an issue.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. If it compiles, it tells the compiler that all the names that are **declared** in that header will be **defined** in that namespace. But the source file that defines those names doesn't know anything about that namespace, and its definitions certainly won't be in it. Don't lie to the compiler. And, yes, if this is a "header only" library, with all the functions defined inline, then it could compile and link. But the result would be that you have **two** versions of every function defined in that header, one inside the namespace and one not. Good luck debugging.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree but if you saw comments section of Q, you will find SO is not ready change any code in library. The best idea is putting all declaration under namespace in library and same is mentioned in my ans.

Comment: @santoshdhanawade -- the fact that the names in that header are being forced into a namespace that isn't part of the library means that calls to functions declared in that namespace **won't link**, because the library versions of the functions aren't defined in that namespace.